# What's the content type of a .ini file?

Tags: mime-types

I'd like to make a dynamically generated `.ini` file available for download, is there a standardized value for the `Content-Type` of `.ini` files?

I've found some places saying it's `text/plain`, but I'm a bit dubious.

Comment: @summea: weird question. A CSS file is a text file, but is sent as `text/css`. A Javascript file is a text file, but is sent as `text/javascript`. An HTML file is a text file, but is sent as `text/html`. Hence my surprise that there doesn't seem to be any `text/ini`?

Comment: Valid point about CSS; I've written an answer below that hopefully clears up any confusion about the content type of an `.ini` file.  Part of the difference between something like a `.css` file vs an `.ini` file is the idea that `.ini` is not directly used with web-related development (other than for configuration purposes, etc.) whereas `.css` is specially used in web development.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Checking with the [IANA list of MIME Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) shows us that `.ini` is not listed in the list of media types (and in particular, in the [list of Text Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text).)

Additionally, [the Wikipedia entry on `.ini` files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) explains that `.ini` files are really just *"simple text files."*

One way to verify these findings is to run the following command on a given `.ini` file (in *nix, at least):

```
$ file --mime-type php.ini.default
```

which gives us the following result:

```
php.ini.default: text/plain
```

Comment: Thanks, the `file` command is a good proof. I've run it on `php.ini` (I guess it could have been different from `php.ini.default`), but it's indeed `text/plain` as well.

Comment: @Benjamin Glad to hear it!

Comment: Well all sorts of specialized file types could be considered “simple text files” but they still deserve a specific MIME type.